# Аналог с Java в PHP

Tags: php, java, mysql

Ребята, нужен аналог на php.

```
 rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lala");
 while(rs.next){
      //do something
 }
```

Comment: @papushaev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: извините, не знал.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM lala");
while($row = $result->fetch()) {
   //do something
}
```